# Is there a road map for TypeScript to output minified JavaScript?

Tags: typescript

Seems like there is no built-in support in TypeScript to automatically minify JavaScript. You have to use external tools like grunt, gulp, npm, uglify to get it minified.

Comment: You can [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) and request this feature

Comment: @NitzanTomer first link should be to issue search page :P

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Yeah, in retrospective you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue on GitHub already, [issue #8](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8) (from 2014)

[Quote from a TypeScript contributor in 2015](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8#issuecomment-98888493):

> Minification has always been one of our most requested features, and one that we have talked about on and off throughout the past few years. It is a substantial amount of work though, assuming you are not just looking for white space removal, and variable name shortening. Moreover, minification has existed in JavaScript tooling for a long time, and there are already multiple minifiers that plug into existing JS workflows. We have been really busy with ES6 and other language/tooling features for TypeScript which made us shy from taking on such a big problem; specially that TypeScript compiles to JavaScript which allows you to leverage any existing JS tools out there.
>   That said, it is not that we are ignoring the issue; it is still open because we believe that there is problem out there that TypeScript can help solve.

as of today, it's not on the [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap), with 2.3 as latest planned release (and future in general)